# Catch externally added data to Postgres database in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, celery

I have a Django backend for my project using Postgres as a DB. Apart from it, I have a systemd service running and inserting a new row in a specific table in the DB. I would need to detect the moment in which a new row is inserted in the table to run a callback function, which is defined in Django. The service takes different times to complete. I would also like to make it efficient. I thought of these options:

1. I used to use celery in the project but don't anymore. It is kind of set up already, so I thought one option would be a PeriodicTask that checks if something has been addedd. I dislike periodic tasks, though, and it is not quite precise (there could be a gap between the time the service finishes and the time the task runs). So EASY but UGLY
2. If it were possible, I would like to use a Postgres TRIGGER to insert my callback task in the Celery queue. On paper, that sounds fast and clean. I have NO CLUE how to add something to the Celery task queue though. So CLEAN and EFFICIENT but DIFFICULT
3. I thought of implementing a separate service which listens to NOTIFY from Postgres, also using TRIGGER. It would then cURL the backend to start the callback function. This seems clunky. So MEH

If it seems like I do not know much of this, you are absolutely correct. I am learning as I go, but this is a must have feature for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can't your systemd service call a django management command after inserting a new row in the DB? Can you share your code for the service?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To be honest, I don't know what a management command is, I'll look into it. On the other hand, the service unit is simply "java -jar file.jar". This java file does some things and writes a result to the DB. Nothing fancy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) and call it after your current execution on your service.

Just to add an example:

```
[Unit]
...

[Service]
...
ExecStart=java -jar file.jar && /.../python /.../manage.py <management_command>

[Install]
...
```

Comment: Sounds excellent. Easy AND clean. Superb. I'll give it a shot and mark it as correct if it works out! Thanks

Comment: @GastonMaffei If it doesn't work, please let me know.

Comment: For what I've tested for now, works fantastic. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just one comment: had to use Type=oneshot and put the second command into a ExecStartPost